# ERROR: Stubs could not be found. Please make sure that spring-cloud-contract:convert was invoked

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Using `Spring Cloud Contract 2.1.3.RELEASE` with `spring-boot 2.1.1.RELEASE`, I have added the dependency and plugin per explained in the guide:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

and

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
```

I have also added under: `$rootDir/src/test/resources/contracts`:

Groovy file:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    name("contract_updateNodeV4")
    request {
        method 'PUT'
        url '/v4/nodes'
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.twitter-places-analyzer.v1+json'
        }
        body(file("updateNodeV4_request.json"))
    }
    response {
        status OK()
        body(file("updateNodeV4_response.json"))
    }
}
```

And corresponding `updateNodeV4_request.json` and `updateNodeV4_response.json` (omitting their contents since these are large) valid JSON files.

When running `mvn clean install` I expected generated tests to be created (and fail for now) per the guide.

Instead I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:1.0.0.RELEASE:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) on project xxx: Stubs could not be found: [C:\Users\xxx\git\xxx\target\stubs] .
[ERROR] Please make sure that spring-cloud-contract:convert was invoked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by moving the  plugin:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
 </plugin>
```

From the root pom.xml to the specific module's pom.xml in which I have created the contracts in. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your contacts are not under the module's src/test/resources/contracts but under the root module's folder. If that's the case you need to tell the plugin that by seeing the contracts dir plugin property

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case. The contracts actually are in fact under the module's `src/test/resources/contracts`. My project is `xxx` and under it I have a module `xxx-web`. I have created the `contracts` folder under `xxx-web`'s resources folder. Any other options that could cause this issue?

Comment: You'll need to upload your sample somewhere

Comment: You can also check the spring cloud contract samples repository at Github where we have both maven and gradle samples

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm afraid my sample is of an enterprise project I cannot simply upload. What I fear the most is that some dependency conflict or incompatibility is causing this issue. First of all please confirm for me that Spring `Cloud Contract 2.2.3.RELEASE` with `Spring-Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE` is compatible, just since I didn't quite understand it from the compatibility matrix.

Comment: There's no such version as 2.2.3. 2.2.0.release will be released in 2 weeks afair. 2.1.x is compatible with boot 2.1. 2.2.x is compatible with boot 2.2

Comment: I apologize, the correct version is `2.1.3.RELEASE`. Updated the typo in my question